# Docusign Demo Org returning full envelope payload instead of envelopeSummary

Tags: docusignapi

We have a docusign demo org where the event call back is returning a different payload then demo orgs.

The application is set up using standard app integration.

The expected response for an event callback is just the envelopeSummary, however this org is returning the full envelope with the expected response nested at data.envelopeSummary.

Our assumption is that this is due a configuration in the demo org, but we have not been able to find anything that would apply to our application.

There are two Connections that are set up, but they are both inactive and are scoped to only a few individuals.

Is anyone aware of a configuration that controls what elements of the envelope data is sent in  the event callback payload?

We have not been able to reproduce this in other developer orgs.

We are posting the the below to:

/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

This is a redacted envelope creation request

```
{
"documents": [{
    "documentBase64": "UEsDBBQACAgIAD19axxx",
    "documentId": "1",
    "fileExtension": ".docx",
    "name": "test-sign-2023-03-08.v1.docx"
}],
"emailBlurb": "Message",
"emailSubject": "test",
"eventNotification": {
    "envelopeEvents": [{
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Sent",
        "includeDocuments": "true"
    }, {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed"
    }, {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Declined"
    }, {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Voided"
    }],
    "eventData": {
        "format": "json",
        "includeData": ["recipients"],
        "version": "restv2.1"
    },
    "loggingEnabled": "true",
    "recipientEvents": [{
        "includeDocuments": "false",
        "recipientEventStatusCode": "Sent"
    }, {
        "includeDocuments": "false",
        "recipientEventStatusCode": "Delivered"
    }, {
        "includeDocuments": "false",
        "recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed"
    }, {
        "includeDocuments": "false",
        "recipientEventStatusCode": "Declined"
    }, {
        "includeDocuments": "false",
        "recipientEventStatusCode": "AuthenticationFailed"
    }, {
        "includeDocuments": "false",
        "recipientEventStatusCode": "AutoResponded"
    }],
    "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
    "url": "https://testxx.com/api/v1/signatures/events/YzQ4MmY5OWQtNjc0OC00MDQyLWEwOWEtNThkYmI0Mjg3Y2ZjX0RPQ1VTSUdOXzQ1OQ=="
},
"recipients": {
    "carbonCopies": [{
        "email": "admin+test@xx.com",
        "name": "admin+test@xx.com",
        "recipientId": "3",
        "routingOrder": "1"
    }],
    "signers": [{
        "email": "admin+test@xx.com",
        "name": "Test Admin",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "tabs": {
            "dateSignedTabs": [{
                "documentId": "1",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "anchorString": "[signature.user_1_date]",
                "tabLabel": "Signed Date"
            }],
            "signHereTabs": [{
                "documentId": "1",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "anchorString": "[signature.user_1]",
                "tabLabel": "Please Sign Here"
            }],
            "textTabs": [{
                "documentId": "1",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "anchorString": "[signature.user_1_name]",
                "tabLabel": "Name",
                "value": "Test Admin",
                "valueMetadata": {
                    "rights": "editable"
                },
                "required": "true",
                "requiredMetadata": {
                    "rights": "editable"
                }
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "email": "tester@yy.com",
        "name": "test",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "tabs": {
            "dateSignedTabs": [{
                "documentId": "1",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "anchorString": "[signature.counterparty_1_date]",
                "tabLabel": "Signed Date"
            }],
            "signHereTabs": [{
                "documentId": "1",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "anchorString": "[signature.counterparty_1]",
                "tabLabel": "Please Sign Here"
            }],
            "textTabs": [{
                "documentId": "1",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "anchorString": "[signature.counterparty_1_title]",
                "tabLabel": "Title",
                "value": "test",
                "valueMetadata": {
                    "rights": "editable"
                },
                "required": "true",
                "requiredMetadata": {
                    "rights": "editable"
                }
            }, {
                "documentId": "1",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "anchorString": "[signature.counterparty_1_name]",
                "tabLabel": "Name",
                "value": "test",
                "valueMetadata": {
                    "rights": "editable"
                },
                "required": "true",
                "requiredMetadata": {
                    "rights": "editable"
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
},
"status": "sent"
```

}

The response we get from the webook looks like this:

```
{
"apiVersion": "v2.1",
"configurationId": 0,
"data": {
    "accountId": "xxx",
    "envelopeId": "xxx",
    "envelopeSummary": {
        "allowMarkup": "false",
        "allowReassign": "true",
        "allowViewHistory": "true",
        "anySigner": null,
        "attachmentsUri": "/envelopes/xxx/attachments",
        "autoNavigation": "true",
        "brandId": "xxx",
        "burnDefaultTabData": "true",
        "certificateUri": "/envelopes/xxx/documents/certificate",
        "createdDateTime": "2023-03-08T15:42:02.98Z",
        "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/xxx/custom_fields",
        "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/xx/documents/combined",
        "documentsUri": "/envelopes/xxx/documents",
        "emailBlurb": "BLUBR",
        "emailSubject": "test",
        "enableWetSign": "true",
        "envelopeId": "xxx",
        "envelopeIdStamping": "true",
        "envelopeLocation": "current_site",
        "envelopeMetadata": {
            "allowAdvancedCorrect": "true",
            "allowCorrect": "true",
            "enableSignWithNotary": "false"
        },
        "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/xxx",
        "expireAfter": "119",
        "expireDateTime": "2023-07-06T15:42:04.9Z",
        "expireEnabled": "true",
        "hasFormDataChanged": "true",
        "initialSentDateTime": "2023-03-08T15:42:04.9Z",
        "is21CFRPart11": "false",
        "isDynamicEnvelope": "false",
        "isSignatureProviderEnvelope": "false",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-03-08T15:42:02.98Z",
        "notificationUri": "/envelopes/xxx/notification",
        "purgeState": "unpurged",
        "recipients": {
            "agents": [],
            "carbonCopies": [
                {
                    "completedCount": "0",
                    "deliveryMethod": "email",
                    "email": "xxx",
                    "firstName": "",
                    "lastName": "",
                    "name": "xxxxxx",
                    "recipientId": "3",
                    "recipientIdGuid": "92e00584-13b5-46d9-bd19-9297a6a1c393",
                    "recipientType": "carboncopy",
                    "requireIdLookup": "false",
                    "routingOrder": "1",
                    "sentDateTime": "2023-03-08T15:42:04.807Z",
                    "status": "completed",
                    "userId": "xxx"
                }
            ],
            "certifiedDeliveries": [],
            "currentRoutingOrder": "2",
            "editors": [],
            "inPersonSigners": [],
            "intermediaries": [],
            "notaries": [],
            "recipientCount": "3",
            "seals": [],
            "signers": [
                {
                    "completedCount": "1",
                    "creationReason": "sender",
                    "deliveredDateTime": "2023-03-08T15:43:26.093Z",
                    "deliveryMethod": "email",
                    "email": "xx@gmail.com",
                    "firstName": "",
                    "isBulkRecipient": "false",
                    "lastName": "",
                    "name": "test",
                    "recipientId": "2",
                    "recipientIdGuid": "4e695e3c-7409-4ecf-915f-c15a5cb696a2",
                    "recipientType": "signer",
                    "requireIdLookup": "false",
                    "requireUploadSignature": "false",
                    "routingOrder": "1",
                    "sentDateTime": "2023-03-08T15:42:04.307Z",
                    "signedDateTime": "2023-03-08T15:43:44.67Z",
                    "status": "completed",
                    "userId": "xxx"
                },
                {
                    "completedCount": "0",
                    "creationReason": "sender",
                    "deliveryMethod": "email",
                    "email": "admin+xxxxxx",
                    "firstName": "",
                    "isBulkRecipient": "false",
                    "lastName": "",
                    "name": "xxx Admin",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "recipientIdGuid": "xxx",
                    "recipientType": "signer",
                    "requireIdLookup": "false",
                    "requireUploadSignature": "false",
                    "routingOrder": "2",
                    "sentDateTime": "2023-03-08T15:43:46.733Z",
                    "status": "sent",
                    "userId": "xxx"
                }
            ],
            "witnesses": []
        },
        "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/xxx/recipients",
        "sender": {
            "accountId": "afff3b79-8960-4da7-b1a3-02c3bec83d67",
            "email": "xx@xxxsoftware.com",
            "userId": "xxx",
            "userName": "xx"
        },
        "sentDateTime": "2023-03-08T15:43:46.78Z",
        "signerCanSignOnMobile": "true",
        "signingLocation": "online",
        "status": "sent",
        "statusChangedDateTime": "2023-03-08T15:43:44.67Z",
        "templatesUri": "/envelopes/xxx/templates"
    },
    "recipientId": "2",
    "userId": "xxx"
},
"event": "recipient-sent",
"generatedDateTime": "2023-03-08T15:42:24.8690000Z",
"retryCount": 7,
"uri": "/restapi/v2.1/accounts/xx/envelopes/xxx"
```

}

In all other instances the webhook response is only the envelopeSummary.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Thanks, I have added a sample of our envelope creation request.

Comment: So this is about the webhook? DocuSign Connect? the webhook includes the document and you don't want that?

Comment: HI yes, this is about the payload that Docusign responds with for envelope events.  I have updated the ticket with the response we are getting.

Comment: You will need to configure a global webhook, not per envelope if you want this. Go to the "Settings" tab in DocuSign and find "Connect" at the bottom-left menu and you can do it there. You will get all the options to configure it as you choose...

Comment: I have multiple demo orgs for various customers, and many production instances where we only get the content of the evelopeSummary back in the webook response. these are all working just fine with out global webhook settings.  If I create a new org today, it will work fine, and return me only the envelopeSummary for events.  We have one customer demo org that returns the above payload.  Since this only effects a single demo org, I was hoping to get some understanding of what can causes the behavior.

Comment: In that case I would suggest you contact support with all the information about the one org/account and so they have the ability to make such changes